# Protecting excel files

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with a number of hidden rows and colums, I would like to lock these rows and colums so other people can't unhide them. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what programming language are you trying to do this?

Comment: not in language.........in Excel itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excels offers a protection functionality, have a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826923/en-us/). You can use the menu entries in Tools -> Protection. I tried it with excel 2003 and it worked fine. More recent excel versions should offer the same (maybe enhanced) functionality.

I would assume you would get more accurate and faster answers on [superusers.com](https://superuser.com/) for questions related to using software instead of developing it.

Comment: Remember, however, that whilst this protection is good against your little brother, it's useless against anyone who really wants to remove the protection. See, for example, http://www.elcomsoft.com

Comment: I agree with smirkingman.  Google "Excel password recovery" and check out the thousands of mini-apps that offer to do it. (And yes, some do work!)